# HTML5 form Pattern match validation for input of 1 to 3 digit number

Tags: html, pattern-matching

How do I pattern match validation for input of 1 to 3 digit number. I tried below and it does not work

```
<input type="text" title="FOO should be a 3 Digit Number Only" pattern="[\d]{3}" id="uid" name="foo<?php echo $i+1;?>" placeholder="Enter FOO" placeholder="FOO" required="'required'" minlength="1" maxlength="3" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a RegEx: `/^\d{1,3}$/` or `^0*\d{1,3}$` to allow numbers starting with any amout of `0`s.

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^\d{1,3}$" />
```

`^` makes sure the string starts with that pattern, and `$` makes sure that it ends with that pattern

You can try your RegEx on websites like https://regex101.com or http://regexr.com

Comment: Works well. Thanks for the links too

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this pattern:

```
pattern="^\d{1,3}$"
```

The other way is to use `maxlength` property like

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="3" />
```

This will make sure that you can have maximum 3 digit number in your textbox.

Comment: you mean type="number", but that will also accept 0 digit numbers and numbers with dots

Comment: Rahul, the input does not work as you described! It just accepts any text with a length from 0 to 3